# Returning const value from arithmetic operator overload with move assignment

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have the following minimal example class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default;

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) {
        std::cout << "copy\n";

        return *this;
    }

    Foo& operator=(Foo&& rhs) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move\n";

        return *this;
    }

    Foo operator+(const Foo& rhs) const {
        Foo x; // with some calculation

        return x;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo a, b, c;

    a = b + c;
}
```

This prints `move` as expected. Now according to Effective C++ Item 3, I should return `const Foo` from `operator+` to avoid construct like `a + b = c`, i.e.:

```
// To avoid a + b = c
const Foo operator+(const Foo& rhs) const {}
```

Unfortunately, this suddenly starts calling copy assignment instead of move assignment operator. [I'm using gcc 4.8.4 on Ubuntu, but it is probably nothing related to compiler]

How can I ensure that `a + b = c` fails to compile and in the same time move assignment is called for `a = b + c`? Or with the introduction of move semantics, is there no way to achieve both of them in the same time?

Comment: That book predates move semantics, and some of it's advice is no longer applicable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know but I want to make sure that `a + b = c` doesn't compile.

Comment: If that's really important, maybe you could label your assignment operators with `&` ? ( [okay](https://ideone.com/bOQwwq), [not okay](https://ideone.com/EZBL5j) ) Not sure if that's a wise thing to do in general, though

Comment: You could return a non-assignable proxy object, though you have to wonder if it's worth it.

Comment: Here, regarding my earlier comment [Should I use lvalue reference qualifiers for assignment operators? (stackoverflow link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759340/should-i-use-lvalue-reference-qualifiers-for-assignment-operators)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux proxy seems overkill for my purpose.

Comment: @Caninonos I wan't aware about lvalue reference qualifier. That looks promising.

Comment: I have never seen anyone write `a + b = c;` by mistake (instead of `a = b + c;`) and then not discover this during testing. Are you *sure* this is something you have to worry about?

Comment: @BoPersson I'm not much worried about writing `a + b = c` by mistake. Instead I'm more interested to learn whether is it still possible to enforce it easily like the way it was before by simply returning `const`.

Comment: @BoPerson On the other hand, by mistake `a + b = c` could be written instead of `a + b == c`.

Comment: Turbo C++ from 1990 introduced the warning "possible incorrect assignment". You guys can stop worrying about = vs == now. That is, given that you have a compiler which isn't worse than TC++ from 1990.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ended up using lvalue reference qualifier as pointed by Caninonos in comment and by max66 in now deleted answer (but 10k users can see it).

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) & {}
Foo& operator=(Foo&& rhs) & noexcept {}
```

It is simple to implement and it provides a better interface design since assignment to anything other that lvalue doesn't sound meaningful and a possible source of bug.

However, it should be noted that the possibility of writing `a + b = c` by mistake is very low. Also compiler generated assignment operators are not lvalue reference qualified and we can write `a + b = c` with standard types, e.g. with `std::string` or with `std::complex`.