# Why & qualifier is used with assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-assignment

My question is in reference to the following links:

[Why declare a deleted assignment operators with the ref-qualifier &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444471/why-declare-a-deleted-assignment-operators-with-the-ref-qualifier)

[Should I use lvalue reference qualifiers for assignment operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759340/should-i-use-lvalue-reference-qualifiers-for-assignment-operators)

I could not follow the posts. Could somebody explain:

1. What does the `&` at the end in the given code snippet actually do? `auto operator=(const string& rhs) &;`.
2. Why does the `&` at the end of this given code snippet is redundant? (Please also confirm if its just redundant or it is problematic) `auto operator=(const string& rhs) & = delete;`
3. Is this statements is valid, `auto operator=(const string&& rhs) &&;`?

If qualifier `&` prevents copy assignment of rvalue, Is it not already taken care by the type of input parameter specified? (`const string& rhs`).

In the following example, with or without qualifier, I get same result for rvalue assignment.

```
class copy_assignment{
   public: 
   copy_assignment& operator=(copy_assignment& a) & {cout << "copied"; return a;}; 
   copy_assignment* get_ca(){return new(copy_assignment);}
};

int main()
{
    copy_assignment a, b;
    a = *b.get_ca();
}
```

Comment: The title of the first question basically answers this: it's a ref-qualifier on a non-static member function. You could research that in a C++ book or on sites like cppreference to find out more.

Comment: The linked posts appear to address the questions. Could you please clarify which part you don't understand?

Comment: *"I could not follow the posts."* is equivalent to *"My code doesn't work."* in terms of information it (doesn't) convey. We don't know what the problem is, we can't explain how to fix it.